# Confusion about Foursquare's Attribution & Linking policy: what other ways can I attribute them besides creating a link?

Tags: api, attributes, foursquare

I see either link them directly or visual attribute them. Example: say my website provides a recommendation directly to a user based on their submitted interest, do I just make sure "powered by Foursquare" shows underneath?

Any help would be appreciated! I'm new to tech development

Answer (score 0):

These policies are generally more vague on purpose. **Rule of thumb: If you're showing any data to users that isn't your own, it should be clear to them where it's coming from.** This is done so the data provider gets proper attribution but also can protect yourself against content being displayed on in your app/site.

For Foursquare specifically, it seems like you would need to include a "[Powered by Foursquare](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kf7rywth02sba55/AADWM1DWQ3BeJWR3ULEQijMga/Logos/Developer?dl=0)" icon and optionally provide a link to the venue if the user may need more information about the place.